# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: discussion

There was a question that just got deleted (~7:20 PM GMT, 2:20 PM EST) regarding a marathon runner and their using a friend's image/name for the charity that they're running for. The question involved the friend, a veteran, committing suicide.

As I was viewing it in the review queue, the website told me that the question had been deleted. That seems a bit abrupt to me. There was one VTC and the question did seem beyond the scope of IPS and probably POB. But why deletion instead of regular putting on-hold then closing?

I mainly ask out of curiosity. My thinking is that there is some rule that we use here on IPS that I just don't know about.

Comment: Hey Lux! I think this is a good (and completely valid) question in the case where something is deleted via moderator actions (whether from the community or unilaterally by a single mod). However, if you're just wondering *how* it happened, feel free to [hop into our chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/61165) next time. There's almost always a high-rep user or three in there who can investigate for you!

Comment: @scohe001 I just assumed that it was moderator intervened. I was surprised by Em C's answer stating that it was self-deletion.

Comment: Trick: You can see that through the 404 error page if you still have a link (usually, there will be one in the chatroom as feeds post all question in there). A 404 page can show a question was deleted 'voluntarily by its author' or 'for reasons of moderation'. The first one is self-deleted, the second a deletion done by other users through vote or moderators. Another link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/369802, under 'what does deletion mean for a post'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/23640/) was deleted by the question asker, not a mod or community action. As mentioned in the comments - even if you don't have the [reputation](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) to view deleted questions, you should see a message like "This question was voluntarily removed by its author." (instead of "for reasons of moderation", which is what happens if other users delete it).

[This article](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) has info on how deleting questions works - since there weren't any answers yet, they were able to self-delete. I'm not sure why they deleted it, but if they want to undelete later (say, because they wanted to do edits without worrying about votes) they should be able to.

Comment: It actually does say "reasons of moderation" when I open the page in incognito.

Comment: @Belle I believe that's because the user removed their account, so there's no user to attribute the deletion too (but not too certain on that).